# OnApp wrapper with Symfony

Tags: cloud, symfony1, symfony-1.4

I have to use [OnApp](http://onapp.com/) (the virtual machine(VM)) api with my webhosting control panel which is written in Symfony. Now I have the on app PHP wrapper files with me.

Anyone have any idea that how can I use with Symfony?

Comment: Could give us more detail? Like: what is OnApp, which product you want to use from OnApp, etc ..

Comment: onApp is a cloud management system. I would like to use the virtual machine(VM) feature from onapp. They are actually providing a php wrapper. But I don't have an idea that where to start with,

Comment: Have you checked the [doc](http://onapp.com/docs/)? It seems to have some php wrapper

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The OnApp API is purely for controlling the virtual machines in your account.  It is for creating, restarting, changing resources, etc for the virtual machines.

Your symfony control panel needs to send cURL commands to the OnApp API.  I will assume you want one virtual machine to manage other virtual machines on your account?  In this case your symfony control panel needs to send out cURL requests to the API or use the classes in the [PHP wrapper](https://github.com/OnApp/OnApp-PHP-Wrapper).

One thing to be careful with is that the virtual machine with the symfony control is just another VM to the OnApp API. So you could have the control panel VM delete itself at worst or reboot the VM...  Might be best to use a server not on the OnApp account.